# Can I use the default music app in ICS without linking it to my google account?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, music-player, google-account

I somehow cannot use the music app in android without linking it to my google account first.

So - against my will - I linked it to my google account. I did this because I was hoping to remove that link later from *within* the app. As it turns out, this is not possible.

I do not use google music and want to avoid granting access to private data when it's not necessary.

### Question

- Can I use the default music app in ICS without linking it to my google account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess this isn't CM9 specific, but based on a quick test on my Kindle Fire you can just hit the `Back` button on the account select screen the first time you launch Music and it will simply skip it. Also, you can unlink your account by clearing the Music app's data in your settings (`Settings->Applications->Music->Clear Data`).